# android: best view class to create popup page

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, camera, android-view

I am developing an android camera app that allow popup of page upon pressing a button (besides the shoot button)in the view of the photo capture activity for accessing twitter services, including login(of coz with button), view tweets(listview or list fragment) of bookmarked users and posting tweets.

I am considering the approach to build the layout for the popup stuff. What come across my mind are dialog fragment, popupwindow and simply another activity.

Considering my case, what view is recommended for the popup component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the content of your popup:

1. If popup contains only a list of items use `PopupWindow`.
2. If popup contains only a few buttons like ok/cancel some text etc. Use `DialogFragment`.
3. If you have more stuff, you should probably use `Activity`.